# Adding objects that are not the same into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to loop through two arrays, compare them and create new array that will contain objects from both arrays but omit ones that are the same:
Code below explains how end result should look like.
Thank you.

```
Array1 = [
    {"column": "brand_name1"},
    {"column": "brand_name2"}
    ]

    Array2 = [
    {"column": "brand_name1"},
    {"column": "brand_name3"}
    ]

    And result should be something like

    Array3 = [
    {"column": "brand_name1"},
    {"column": "brand_name2"},
    {"column": "brand_name3"}
    ]
```

Comment: Is the comparison always based on one key (`column` in this case)?

Comment: You want the values that are the same to be omited, but you have {"column": "brand_name1"} in your result array. Do you mean instead that you don't want duplicates?

Comment: @Philzax Yes that is correct, if all properties match ( or in this snippet one ), it should only appear once in new array. Yes, in new array there should be no duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `O(n)` solution for getting the unique array from the two array of objects.

```js
var Array1 = [{
    "column": "brand_name1"
  },
  {
    "column": "brand_name2"
  }
]

var Array2 = [{
    "column": "brand_name1"
  },
  {
    "column": "brand_name3"
  }
]

var newArray = [...Array1, ...Array2];
var tempObj = {};
newArray.forEach((item) => {
  var value = Object.values(item)[0];
  if(!tempObj[value]){
    tempObj[value] = item;
  }
});
var Array3 = Object.values(tempObj);
console.log(Array3);
```

Comment: It works perfectly Ankit, thank you so much ! JS looks really easy when other people do it, but I figured out harder way that it is not. You are the best !

Comment: It makes me to wait 10 minutes before making the answer :) do not worry I am look at the clock

Comment: @Milosh oh i see. cool :)